# How do I prevent the render function from outputting a file with Jquery functions

Tags: javascript, html, r

I have an R script that calls the `render` function and outputs an HTML file. The HTML file opens and runs properly when manually opening it on my machine, but I'm also trying to use the HTML file in a subsequent function when I use it as the body of an email to be sent. This emailing function doesn't work, I think because the HTML file is too big - it has these huge Jquery functions.

I'm able to programmatically send an email using the HTML file after I've removed the Jquery functions, so that's why I think it's the length of the file that is the issue. I would copy the functions here, but they're long, more than 30,000 characters long.

I'm not familiar enough with Jquery or HTML to understand what the functions are doing. I looked through the documentation for `render` and tried playing around with the various parameters to try to remove these huge jquery functions but without any luck. Here's a small snippet of the functions:

```
<script>/*! jQuery v1.11.3 | (c) 2005, 2015 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */
!function(a,b){"object"==typeof module&&"object"==typeof module.exports?module.exports=a.doc
```

Is there anything I can do to try to remove these? Any way to supress these? Where are they exactly generated from?

Comment: I voted to mark this as a duplicate. In the linked question, there are several approaches listed. If you try those and your problem isn't solved, please edit your question to say so.

Comment: Perfect, that was super helpful since I guess I should have been searching more for other terms